# Is there an action window to trigger abilities once the point limit has been reached?

Tags: android-netrunner

If the runner access an agenda which gives them enough points to win the game, but the corporation is Jinteki and deals 1 net damage as a result which is enough to kill the player and win the game, which side wins?

I think that the general rules on triggered abilities and simultaneous actions state that the player who's turn it is can resolve the order, but it isn't clear if this applies to win conditions as well. This would mean the runner wins in this situation, is that correct?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's not actually completely simultaneous; the Runner wins the game.

From the [Android: Netrunner FAQ](http://www.fantasyflightgames.com/ffg_content/android-netrunner/support/FAQ/Android-Netrunner%20FAQ.pdf):

> **If the Runner steals an agenda from Jinteki using the core set identity, but has no cards in hand, who wins?**
>   The Runner wins the
>   game. Whenever a player has 7 or more  agenda points in his score
>   area, the game immediately ends. The  game ending takes precedence
>   over any conditional ability that  triggers when an agenda is stolen.

Comment: Ah, including that FAQ with the boxed set would have been helpful!

Answer (score 0):

There is one simultaneous win condition that can happen.

Corp Score Area:

- Vanity Project  4pts
- Merger 2pts (worth one more in Runner score area)

Runner Score Area:

- Global Food Initiative  2pts (3pt agenda worth one less in runner score area)
- Vanity Project 4pts

So both corp and runner are at 6pts, the runner just stole Global Food Initiative and triggers the swap effect from Turntable and swaps GFI with Merger.  I used Vanity project as a filler to shorten the post.  Those could easily be other 2pt agendas.

Simultaneous win achieved.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Boardgames StackExchange! Whilst this is an interesting piece of information, I don't think it directly addresses the question!

Comment: It answers the title question.  :)

Simultaneous win conditions in Android: Netrunner?